# Azure Web Service / SSL - Renewal Procedure

Tags: ssl, azure

I have a WCF service being hosted on the Microsoft Azure Web Services platform.

I wish to secure the service using SSL. I have the domain with GoDaddy and will be buying an SSL certificate through them.

I am fairly happy with the procedure to add a certificate to Azure. My question is the following:

After 1 year, what is the procedure. My original cert (A) will expire, and a new certificate (B) will take over as the SSL cert. During the period of the change I will need to maintain uptime of my service via SSL.

How does this work? Can somebody explain to me how I can make sure that there is a sufficient overlap between A and B.

Comment: Put the date on your Outlook calendar? I'm really not seeing the point of this question.

Comment: I can only assume I haven't made myself clear. What I don't understand is can there be two certificates valid at the same time so that there is safe overlap? Or is that not how SSL works? @MichaelHampton

Comment: You renew it before it expires, like your driver license. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resell SSL Certificates for Thawte on a fairly regular basis.

When you go to renew your SSL Certificate around the time that it is near it's expiration, most if not all Certificate Authorities(CA) will add the remaining validity time onto your newly renewed certificate.

For example, if you had an SSL certificate for `secure.domain.com.au` and you received a notice from your CA that it was going to expire in 90 days from now, you could renew it straight away and your new certificate would have the 12 months of validity (or whatever period you renew it for) **PLUS the 90 days that you had remaining in the first place**.

Swapping out an old SSL certificate with a new one should not cause any interruption to your service, as long as the certificate is valid.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ah ok, that was the answer I was looking for. Thanks Vasili

Answer (score 0):

You have to renew it before it expires, and change the certificate on the server before the expiration date.

Source: I'm a very technologically knowledgable 12 year old seventh grader who has worked on countless technologies, both client side and server side.